# I need to take the first N characters from the input

Tags: java, numbers, output

I'm just starting on Java. I need to take the first N characters from the input. The input includes the number of characters at the begining of the input String then characters. The output includes the number at the begining.

An example, if user inputs "3stars", output would be "3st", or input "7appendices" output would be "7append".

Have tried the following:

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
      String first = input.nextLine();
      input.close();

      if (first.charAt(0) == 'u') {
          first = first.toUpperCase();
      } else if (first.charAt(0) == 'l') {
          first = first.toLowerCase();
      } else if (first.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
                str += first.charAt(i);
            }
            first = str;
        } else if (first.charAt(0) == 'o') {
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
                str += first.charAt(i);
            }
            first = str;
        } else if (first.charAt(0) == 1++) {
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 1++ ; i < first.length(i); i = i charAt(i)) {
                str += first.charAt(i);
            }
            first = str;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please include the full code that you've tried rather than just this block in the middle.

Comment: Is last "if else" part.

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.charAt(0) - '0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
int num = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(0));

String str = "";
for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){
   str += first.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: how would that be incorporated into the "else if". Just getting an error. Also is the "str += first,charAt(i)" the portion that adjusts output?

Comment: "if user inputs "3stars", output would be "3st"" => the code i posted does this :D

Comment: Just starting out, how would the final "else if" look:  }

Comment: } else int num = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(0));
       String str = "";
       for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){
        str += first.charAt(i);

Comment: Thanks for this too.

Comment: else {  int num = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(0)); String str = ""; for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){ str += first.charAt(i);  }

Comment: Got that to work. Thats great. Will have a look at that now.

Answer (score 0):

this works also with input like `11abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` with numbers greater than 9

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "7appendices";
    // match numbers
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+)");
    // by default at least the integer has one digit
    int digits = 1;
    int length = 0;
    // while the beginning of the input match an integer
    while (p.matcher(input.substring(0, digits)).matches()) {
        // set length as the integer at the beginning
        length = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, digits));
        // increase the amount of digits from the integer in the input
        digits++;
    }
    System.out.println(input.substring(0, length));
}
```

You only have to replace the input with `scanner` like this

```
 String input = new Scanner(System.in).next();
```